# redirect access to image Symfony 3 .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website for GIFs and I want when a user tries to access to a GIF they will be redirected to another route.
For example, if they type in the URL bar https://example.com/gif/YqHiZ3Mp.gif
they will be redirected to https://example.com/gif/embed/YqHiZ3Mp

I tried this in .htaccess but nothing happened

```
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteRule ^gif/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.gif$ /gif/embed/$1 [L,NC] 
</IfModule>
```

Also which .htaccess do I have to edit? under /web directory?

Comment: First thing jumps out... `<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>` If *no* mod_rewrite? Also, usually first thing emitted in those blocks is `RewriteEngine On`. As for where? In the directory the request is being served from.

Comment: But still does not work
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteRule ^gif/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.gif$ /gif/embed/$1 [L,NC] 
</IfModule>`

Answer (score 0):

I find this solution

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^gif/([a-z\d]+)\.(gif)$ /gif/embed/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

but when I try to call a GIF with HTML or javascript it will be redirected too.
Is there any way to ignore this rule when the call comes from code?